# StackView inside UIView - auto-height

Tags: uiview, uistackview, stackview

It's possible to make an UIView adjust automatically his height to accommodate an StackView, via Interface Builder? I' wanna put a background on a StackView, but as long it is not possible, as StackView is not renderable, I'm using it inside a UIView, but XCode is complaining about a height constraint.

Thanks a lot[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkFun.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to constraint top, bottom, leading, trailing of the `UIView` to the `UIStackView`, and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro. Actually I need the StackView to be constrained to the UIView. I have solved the problem putting a height constraint from the UIView to the height of the StackView. It worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes the answer is so obvious that we can't see it. I've just put a **height constraint** of the **UIView** to the **height** of the **StackView** and it worked like a charm!